# Create query for specific summarizing in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL named `SupplyIndex`:

```
ID          PartName Index
----------- -------- -----------
1           C        1
2           C        2
3           C        3
4           C        10
5           C        20
6           C        21
7           B        5
8           B        6
9           B        7
10          B        8
```

I want to convert this table to `IndexReport` table for using it in my reports in VB.Net like below:

```
PartName Index                      
-------- --------------------------
C        (1 to 3), 10, (20 to 21)   
B        (5 to 8)
```

I can do this in VB but I am to do that in SQL with query or SP directly in SQL.

Would you please help me?

Comment: what database engine are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to group each `PartName` with continuous `Index`. You can do that using `ROW_NUMBER`. And then after the grouping, find the `MIN` and `MAX` of each group to be used for concatenation. When `MIN` and `MAX` is not the same, format the string so that it follows the pattern: `'(MIN to MAX)'`.

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        grp = [Index] - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PartName ORDER BY [Index])           
    FROM SupplyIndex
)
SELECT
    s.PartName,
    x.[Index],
    s.Qty
FROM (
    SELECT 
        PartName, COUNT(*) AS Qty
    FROM SupplyIndex
    GROUP BY PartName
) s
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' +
            CASE
                WHEN MIN(c.[Index]) = MAX(c.[Index]) THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MIN(c.[Index]))
                ELSE '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MIN(c.[Index])) + ' to ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MAX(c.[Index])) + ')'
            END
        FROM Cte c
        WHERE c.PartName = s.PartName
        GROUP BY c.PartName, c.grp
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') AS [Index]
)x
ORDER BY s.Qty DESC
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/470374)</kbd>